# How can I align the handles of control points from a curve?

Tags: modeling, transforms, bezier-curves

I made a curve but part of the same curve doesn't fit in a regular line, I need to align the points/vertices with each other, how can I do this? I need to put those in order.

[image]

Comment: @RayMairlot A duplicate of a duplicate... really?

Comment: Select all the ones on the same line and scale to zero on whichever axis.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't working for me, this is a Bezier Curve, and when i select three vertices for example, and if i press G + Y + 1 they all move, but doesnt appear in the same position :/

Comment: .blend file please? Did you try `S`-`Y`-`0`? It works for me with Vector handles.

Comment: Oh, i just tried that and now that i look at it, it worked! the problem now are the distances between the lines, but i think that could be another question.

Comment: I'll write an answer then

Comment: @PGmath The top answer on the answer I linked to seemed slightly more relevant. Either way, it seems like a duplicate of one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is scale along a single axis, in this case the Y axis. Select the vertices you want to have in a straight line, and press <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>.

**Instead of this:**
[image]

**You will now have this:**
[image]

This works best for the Vector handle type, but can be used in many cases for the other types as well.

Comment: No problem! Always here to help!